# Compatible compilers for Matlab R2015a

Tags: software-installation, matlab, compiler

I was trying to install Matlab R2015a, and everything was running perfectly till this message appeared and left me puzzled because as you can see, I already have installed all the compilers needed to run Matlab.

[image: InstallationMessage.]

Apparently the installation was successful.

[image: InstallationFinished.]

Nonetheless, the software does not run even after changing the Matlab file permissions.

I also installed the Matlab support, but it didn't help either.

It would be great help for me if I could get any kind of help from the community. What is missing? What should I have not done? And finally what should I do?

As requested I'm posting the output from `cat /etc/lsb-release`:

```
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

And from `apt-cache policy gcc g++`:

```
    gcc:
    Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
    Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
    Version table:
    *** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
            500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    g++:
      Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
      Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
      Version table:
     *** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
            500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Your problem statement is highly unclear. Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @cat Ok, but in the picture we can see that gcc is already installed, right? What details you think are important to mention?

Comment: My mistake; I still don't know what you're asking. What happened when you clicked `Next >`?

Comment: It just ended the installation. No error messages... and no installation error messages! I going to edit and put the image so you can see it, ok?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question to include the output of commands `cat /etc/lsb-release` and `apt-cache policy gcc g++`

Comment: So what "software does not run" exactly? I think mex should work with gcc/g++ 4.8 even though it's officially unsupported, however you should be able to install gcc-4.7/g++4.7 from the repo and (if necessary) modify your mexopts.sh accordingly

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, the Terminal was hanging without any reaction for several minutes and my aptop is quite fast... Anyways I explained what was wrong in one of my answers!

Answer (score 3):

Did you update your repositories? And did you try installing the matlab-support package.

```
sudo apt-get matlab-support
```

If you are facing problem with your version. Try this one.

https://kat.cr/mathworks-matlab-r2015a-amd64-linux-t11790580.html

I have successfully installed it from here. But remember,

1. First unpack the iso extension file by right clicking on it. Then you will get the original `.iso` file.
2. Use this command to mount the iso file:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 (source_path_where_you_have_downloaded) /media/iso
   ```

Please let me know if you have any further questions. And when you are doing all these if you are in root mode then you should not have any permission problems.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try installing again... I already have installed this matlab-support though it didn't really helped me... Should I remove it before reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help. It looks like the problem was much simpler than I had thought. What was preventing Matlab to run was the Firewall. I was trying to run as superuser, but it always would hang, correcting I thought it had hanged, but a forgot to shut down the Terminal and it printed a problem with the connection.
After disabling the Firewall everything is running. Sorry for the beginners mistake.
Thanks again!